# How to clip and assign points to individual polygons of shapefile

Tags: arcgis

I'm in a little over my head on this one. I have approximately 300 shapefiles containing about 7000 polygons, each of which I'm trying to clip a systematic grid of points. Each shapefile has a unique number of polygons (buffers around a point location) and I need to have the grid points assigned to each polygon so that they can be recognized as discrete sets later on.

For example, polygon 1 in shapefile 1 will have a set of grid points associated with it. Polygon 2 in shapefile 1 will have another set of grid points, including many that may be the same as those in polygon 1. I would need an attribute field that identifies those points as belonging to that polygon. If it helps, this is for a discrete choice model being applied to resource selection. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[Image: Polygons with grid points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUUib.jpg).

[Image: Single shapefile containing polygons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpMbp.jpg)

Comment: You'll find ArcGIS Q&As on this at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Using Intersect should connect the two layers in a new feature class with one attribute table.

You can also try Spatial Join which will ad the table of one layer to the table of the other according to location.